# MYSQLConnection call to @database.setter incorrectly routes to the _mysql_connector c-extenstion

Tags: mysql-connector-python, mysql-connector-c

Running on Mac Big Sur 11.6.2
Using Python 3.8
Mysql 8.0.29 Homebrew

MYSQLConnection call to @database.setter, i.e. db_conn.database = my_db_name, incorrectly routes to the _mysql_connector c-extenstion, but I don not have the c extension installed, so the call raises an exception. After pip install mysql-connector-python the file WHEEL contains Root-Is-Purelibe: true and top_level.txt is missing _mysql_connector. I expect calling db_conn.database = my_db_name to execute the MySQLConnection class’ database(value) method in connection.py, not route the call to a non-existent  _mysql_connector I have been unable to get pip to install the mysql-connector-python with c extension despite trying various suggestions in stackoverflow.

Comment: If you're using a M1 processor (arm64) there's no Connector/Python wheel package with the c-ext for this platform yet. This will be addressed in the upcoming release. Nonetheless, it shouldn't raise any error when using the pure Python implementation. Can you provide a complete snippet that raises the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't a reputation yet to reply in comment to Nuno-Mariz, so posting the following.

I work on the same team as @needpythonhelp, and we have nearly identical macbook pro laptops, they are not M1. We use the the same Pipfile to create a project-specific .venv.  His does not get the _mysql_connector, and my .venv does (I don't remember how I got my python 3.8 version a year ago).  See difference below.  Could his lack of _mysql_connector have anything to do with missing CPPFLAGS or LDFLAGS when his Python version was installed (presumably built from source e.g. pyenv or annaconda)?

**My system**

```
clang --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (v3.8.5:580fbb018f, Jul 20 2020, 12:11:27)
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

cat .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql_connector_python-8.0.23.dist-info/WHEEL
Wheel-Version: 1.0
Generator: bdist_wheel (0.35.1)
Root-Is-Purelib: false
Tag: cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64

cat .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql_connector_python-8.0.23.dist-info/top_level.txt
_mysql_connector
_mysqlxpb
mysql
mysqlx

ls -la .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_mysql*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 brian  staff  7876288 May 25 18:53 .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_mysql_connector.cpython-38-darwin.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 brian  staff  3190548 May 25 18:53 .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_mysqlxpb.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

**needpythonhelp's system**

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

$ python3
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul 2 2020, 11:26:31)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
```

his WHEEL file has

```
Root-Is-Purelib: true
Tag: py2-none-any
Tag: py3-none-any
```

top_level.txt

```
mysql
mysqlx
```

he does not have either of these in .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages

```
_mysqlxpb.cpython-38-darwin.so
_mysql_connector.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

Edit/Update to the above info

I did a test later today where I used pyenv to install the latest CPython 3.8.13, and built a new .venv from the same Pipfile as noted above.  This .venv is like @needpythonhelp's .venv. So now I have one .venv (CPython 3.8.13) that does NOT have _mysql_connector  and Root-Is-Purelib: false, etc., and another .venv (from my original CPython 3.8.5 installed a year ago) that does have it.

This is what my Pyenv install today looked like:

```
❯ pyenv install 3.8:latest
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.13.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.13/Python-3.8.13.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.13...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Installed Python-3.8.13 to /Users/brian/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13
```

Any ideas on how to consistently get the c-ext when I use pyenv to install new Python versions?